# for loop and appending over list of arrays

Tags: variable, array, debugging, for, bash-array

I am new to Bash scripting and presently find myself dealing with a small problem in working with for loops, arrays and variable assignment/substitution which I do not know how to solve. Since I am quite literally **new**, I do not even know how to look this up. Although anyone could say this, I stress that this isn't homework or anything of the sort - I just need to reorganize a humongous amount of data for later processing and thought I'd do it in a somewhat *smart* way while learning some Bash.

**Background**:
I have a directory which itself contains three subdirectories - Folder1, Folder2, Folder3. Each subdirectory has **one** data.txt file. Each data.txt file features three columns with a fixed number of rows.

**Goal**:
I want to launch a Bash script from the main directory which iterates over the subdirectories and carries out the following:

1. it enters and accesses the data.txt;
2. it reads each column into the corresponding array `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3` (these are emptied/reset when entering the next subdirectory);
3. it reads `arr2[0]` into `earr1`, `arr2[1]` into `earr2`, ..., `arr2[j-1]` into `earr$j`. A similar structure is followed for the data in `arr3`. The `earr$j` keep the data from past iterations and constitute my desired output arrays. With every sweep of a new directory, data are appended to these.

It sounds overly complicated - but that's the structure of the data I have to work with. For the most part, I have figured out a working solution (granted, probably not the best one).

**Problem**:
For some reason I am not able to identify, I am getting all kinds of errors with every attempt at appending as `earr$j+=(${arr2[j-1]})` (and all sorts of variations I have tried out) in a loop over `j`. Below is the snippet giving me trouble. I would appreciate if someone could point out how what the problem is and, if possible, provide a working example of a solution.

The for-loop in question:

`for j in $(seq 1 $number_of_lists); do echo "(${arr2[j-1]})"; earr$j+=(${arr2[j-1]}); echo "(${arr3[j-1]})"; done`

In particular, I have trouble with the `earr$j+=(${arr2[j-1]})` part. This is my error output:

`./next.sh: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token "${arr2[j-1]}''`
and `./next.sh: line 33:     earr$j+=('${arr2[j-1]}')`.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.