# For-loop - appending to arrays with iterator in the array name

Tags: variable, array, for, bash-array

I have the following problem. I have an array `arr` with some values. I want to sort each value into a set of different - and already declared - arrays `earr$j`, i.e. `arr[0]` into `earr1`, `arr[1]` into `earr2` and, in general, `arr[j-1]` into `earr$j`. (Later, I will have the elements of similar `arr`s be appended as the next elements of the target `earr$j`s). I have tried doing so with the following snippet of code (which is part of a larger piece of code):

```
for j in $(seq 1 $number_of_elements); do earr$j+=(${arr[j-1]}); done
```

I have been told (see my post "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675454/for-loop-and-appending-over-list-of-arrays") it looks as though I intend to create a 2-D array (which Bash does not support). I stress that this is not my intention, regardless of what the result of my poor use of Bash syntax may suggest. I am reposting this as my old post really described the issue poorly.

Comment: Given you're using the array assignment syntax (with the parens), `earrN` must be arrays themselves, and if we look at a set of variables named `foo1`, `foo2`, etc. that does look a lot like an array in itself. Though you're right, it's not a 2D-array, but an array of arrays, since it doesn't need to be rectangular.

Comment: Use perl. Or python. Or awk.  Or any language that isn't shell.  Shell is a terrible language for doing data processing in.  Perl, for example, supports arrays-of-arrays (AoA), arrays-of-hashes (AoH), as well as HoAs and HoHs, and multi-level data structures based on them nested as many levels deep as you need.   It will be **much** easier, and your code will run much faster.

Comment: BTW, one of the benefits of arrays in shell implementations that support them (bash, ksh, zsh, etc) is that you don't have to do that ugly and human-error-prone variable indirection (like `earr$j`) any more, so why even do that?    IMO you probably need to rethink your data structure from the ground up.   And, as I said above, use a language that's actually suited to processing data instead of a language that's suited to co-ordinating the execution of other programs to do the data-processing work.

Comment: I thank both of you for answering. I'll give it all a thought. It's odd however, isn't it? That I cannot just access the value in the j-th element of an array and append this value to another array (which happens to have j in its name).

Comment: As for using other scripting languages, I'll have to see. This is all done on a cluster, so unfortunately whatever is or gets installed on it does not depend on my needs. This is also one of the reasons I want to do this step in Bash: since I am not sure whether I have the means to do the actual processing on the cluster and will likely do it outside, I want to extract just the minimum amount of relevant data. Similarly, there is not much I can do about the data structure I am trying to pre-process. If anything, I may need to come up with a different idea and forget about the `arr` arrays.

Comment: Well, not the bare minimum, as I am extracting everything. But extracting all the information as one file with an amenable data structure.

Comment: Last question: to simplify it even further, isn't it possible to do `for j in $(seq 1 $number_of_elements); do earr$j+=(1); done` ? I.e. to append the number 1 to different arrays `earr1`, `earr2`, ..., with a simple loop? I am just trying to wrap my head around why even this gives me an error. If the answer is that one cannot do this in Bash, I'll of course go with it, but it just seems weird. I'd expect this to be an error due to wrong syntax on my side - otherwise (and with all due respect), it really feels like a shortcoming of the language.

Comment: no, that will give you a syntax error because shell won't see `earr$j` as one token (variable name), it will split the token at the `$` sign, not construct a token from the fixed string `earr` and the value of `$j`.   Try `eval "earr$j+=(1)"` instead.   Note that `eval` is potentially dangerous and should be used with caution - it tells your shell to evaluate the string and execute it.   `eval` has its uses, but most of those uses are awkwardly trying to work around a deficiency in shell.   have i suggested using a better language yet? :-)

Comment: Hi. Thank you again. Regardless of your suggestion of using another language, I really just wanted to dissect and understand what was going on in the code. Which is why I have iteratively broken down my question to - I believe - the simplest possible scenario in my last comment. Perhaps I should have started from there, but, alas, this is how it has played out. Thank you for your time. I'll check if I can use another language on the cluster in question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question literally, here, that's typically a job for `eval`:

```
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
  eval '
    earr'"$i"'+=( "${arr[i]}" )
  '
done
```

`eval` is dangerous, but safe if used properly. A good approach to limit the risk of mistake is to quote everything with single quotes except the parts that definitely need do undergo some expansion and make sure the part that is not within single quotes (here `$i` which is in double quotes instead and will be expanded to the contents of the `i` variable) is fully under your control. In this case, we know `$i` will contain only digits, so that's not random data that `eval` would evaluate as shell code (compare with `${arr[i]}` that you definitely don't want to leave out of the single quotes).

I still don't see why you'd say 2D arrays are not appropriate. In `ksh93` (`bash` copied most of its syntax from ksh93, but didn't copy multidimensional arrays), you'd do:

```
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
  earr[i]+=( "${arr[i]}" )
done
```

In any case, unless there's a specific reason why you need to use a shell, I agree with @cas that it sounds like you'd be better off using a proper programming language such as `perl` or `python`.

Comment: Hi Stéphane. Thank you too for your answer. I have managed to solve my issue (more or less) using the `eval` command as suggested by @cas. I will try out your suggestion as well, which is a tad different (although I expect the same result). I fully agree with both of you that I might try using a different language in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do what you described using perl and a Hash-of-Array-of-Arrays (HoAoA) data structure.

To help in understanding this, the following man pages will be useful: `perldata` (perl data types),  `perldsc` (data structures), `perllol` (lol = lists of lists), `perlref` (references) and `perlreftut` (tutorial for references).   You can also get details on specific perl functions with the `perldoc` command - e.g. `perldoc -f opendir` or `perldoc -f grep`.

Note that the `sort` and `grep` used in the script are built-in perl functions.  They are **not** the `sort` and `grep` command-line tools...you can call those from perl if you want to (with backticks or `qx` quoting, or the `system()` function, or with the `open()` function to open a pipe, and several other ways).   Use `perldoc` for details on all of these and more.

```
$ cat HoAoA.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

# $h is a ref to Hash-of-Array-ofArrays (HoAoA).
#
# This will be a data structure with the directory names
# (Folder1, Folder2, Folder3) as the hash keys of the top-level
# hash.  Each element of that hash will be an array where the
# indexes are the line numbers of the data.txt files in each
# of those directories. The data in these second-level arrays
# will be an array containing the three values in each line of
# data.txt: $$h{directory}[line number][element]
my $h;

# get the directory name from the first command line arg, default to ./
my $dir = shift // './';

# get a list of subdirectories that contain 'data.txt',
# excluding . and ..
opendir(my $dh, "$dir") || die "Couldn't open directory $dir: $!\n";
my @dirs = sort grep { $_ !~ /^\.+$/ && -d $_ && -f "$_/data.txt" } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

dd \@dirs;   # Data::Dump's dd function is great for showing what's in an array
print "\n";

foreach my $d (@dirs) {
  my $f = "$d/data.txt";
  open(my $fh,"<",$f) || die "Couldn't open file $f: $!\n";
  my $lc=0;  # line counter
  while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;   # strip trailing newline char at end-of-line
    my @row = split /\s*,\s*/;   # assume simple comma-delimited values
    push @{ $$h{$d}[$lc++] }, @row;
  }
  close($fh);
}

# dd is even better for showing complex structured data
dd $h;
print "\n";

# show how to access individual elements, e.g. by changing the
# zeroth element of line 0 of 'Folder1' to 999.
$$h{'Folder1'}[0][0] = 999;

dd $h;
print "\n";

# show how to print the data without using Data::Dump
# a loop like this can also be used to process the data.
# You could also process the data in the main loop above
# as the data is being read in.
foreach my $d (sort keys %{ $h }) {   # `foreach my $d (@dirs)` would work too
  print "$d/data.txt:\n";
  foreach my $lc (keys @{ $$h{$d} }) {
    print "  line $lc: ", join("\t",@{ $$h{$d}[$lc] }), "\n";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Note: the above is written to process simple comma-delimited data files.  For actual CSV, with all its quirks and complications (like multi-line double-quoted fields with embedded commas), use the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module.  This is a third-party library module that isn't included with the core perl distribution.  On Debian and related distros you can install this with `apt-get install libtext-csv-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl`. Other distros probably have similar package names. Or you can install it with `cpan` (a tool to install and manage library modules that IS included with perl core).

Also note: the above script uses the [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-Dump).    This is a third-party module which is useful for dumping structured data.  Unfortunately, it's not included as part of the perl core library.  On Debian etc `apt-get install libdata-dump-perl`.  Other distros will have a similar package name.  And, as a last resort, you can install it with `cpan`.

Anyway, with the following folder structure and data.txt files:

```
$ tail */data.txt
==> Folder1/data.txt <==
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

==> Folder2/data.txt <==
7,8,9
4,5,6
1,2,3

==> Folder3/data.txt <==
9,8,7
6,5,4
3,2,1
```

running the HoHoA.pl script produces the following output:

```
$ ./HoAoA.pl 
["Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3"]

{
  Folder1 => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
  Folder2 => [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]],
  Folder3 => [[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]],
}

{
  Folder1 => [[999, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
  Folder2 => [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]],
  Folder3 => [[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]],
}

Folder1/data.txt:
  line 0: 999   2       3
  line 1: 4     5       6
  line 2: 7     8       9

Folder2/data.txt:
  line 0: 7     8       9
  line 1: 4     5       6
  line 2: 1     2       3

Folder3/data.txt:
  line 0: 9     8       7
  line 1: 6     5       4
  line 2: 3     2       1
```

Comment: BTW, the above doesn't really **need** Data::Dump - if it's not installed on your cluster, and you can't get your admins to install it for you, and you can't install it on the compute nodes with `cpan` then just get rid of it from the script.   Data::Dump is just a convenient pretty-printing tool to do essentially the same thing as the last output loop in the script does anyway.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! As I said in my comments above, whether I can use Perl or not does not entirely depend on me. I suppose it will be possible, though, and your suggestion may come in handy. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: perl is probably installed on your cluster, especially if it's running linux...core perl, at least, if not the cpan modules.  Otherwise, python almost certainly will be -  python is a very popular language for scientific computing and HPC users.   Depending on how you need to process the data in your data.txt files, python may be a better choice than perl.  Also, if you have lots of python users nearby that you can ask for help from, that would also make it a better choice.